# Convention for ActiveRecord model names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, naming-conventions, naming

What is the naming convention for models in Rails? If my model is about flying cars, which of the following class names is most appropriate?

```
class FlyingCar < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :model, :max_speed
end

class Flying_Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :model, :max_speed
end

class Flying_car < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :model, :max_speed
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

FlyingCar is the Ruby convention. This becomes even more important when ActiveRecord is trying to do its magic.  There's ways you can override this behavior, but using FlyingCar is what ActiveRecord expects.

Answer (score 1):

Your model class name must be PascalCase (FlyingCar) **and** it must be singular.

For controller classes it's PascalCase, plural, **and** ends with Controller (so: FlyingCarsController)